# IPhone App with multiple controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am developing an app(using Storyboard) with sign-in screen(UIViewController) which takes the authenticated user to Tab application(UITabbarController). One of the Tab Bar Item is based on Table View Controller for which I added UINavigationController. For developing Table screens, I am following iOS 5 part 2(Bird Sighting Example).I've successfully created whole app except this table part.I'm confused in AppDelegate because my root view controller is sign in screen while in BirdSighting example and in most of the examples, app starts from either Navigation View Controller or Tabbar Controller. I'm pasting my AppDelegate method.

This is run time error I am getting
 "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'"

This is my app flows
Sign in screen->
Tab Application
Tab1. Show Details
Tab2. View Ticket(TicketMasterViewController) ->Ticket Details(TicketDetailViewController).

Should I need to initialise all controllers in AppDelegate and what should be the objectAtIndex for TicketMasterViewController.
Thanks for your time.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    NavigationViewController *vc4=[[NavigationViewController alloc]init];


    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc4];
    TicketMasterViewController *firstViewController=(TicketMasterViewController *)[[navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    TicketDataController *aDataController=[[TicketDataController alloc] init];
    firstViewController.dataController=aDataController;  

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: So you have to add tab bar on view controller?

Comment: In your flow two tab have show detail and view tickets and what is ticket details?From where it came out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the above code and the app will probably run.  You shouldn't need this code if you are using storyboards and assuming that you have setup this view controller hierarchy as described above.  The only reason to add code here wold be to attach data (a model in MVC) to a view controller.